# Basketball board arduino endlessly transmitting shot scored

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, hc-05, proximity

I've been working on trying to get [this](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/marceloavilaoliveira/smart-basketball-scoreboard-f922cb#schematics) arduino project I found to work but I've been encountering some problems.

The project was designed for an Arduino mega 2560 but I've been using my UNO and breadboard for it along with the Software Serial library. I'm very, very new to working with Arduinos so if there are any basic things I might be missing please do mention them.

Components:

- Arduino UNO
- Bluetooth HC-05 module
- E18-D80NK Proximity Sensor
- Saeed Grove 420 Proximity Sensor
- 10k Ohm resistor
- Breadboard
- The included app in the above link

The issues I'm facing are

a)Initially, the proximity sensor would detect if I e.g. moved my hand infront of it and send the data to the app and it would increment the score and play the sound.

However, if I tried flicking the vibration sensor and not moving my hand infront of the proximity sensor, a miss wouldn't be recorded. Initially, even just flicking the proximity sensor would record a score as well, but later it would just do nothing.

b)I'm not sure what is the problem, but now nothing happens at all. The wiring and everything is all connected in the same way as before, but now even though the proximity sensor lights up if I move my hand infront of it, no scores are transmitted by the HC-05 module or anything. I have tried keeping the Serial Monitor open but nothing is printed on it.

Also, the code I've pasted below is after including the SerialSoftware library header and after deleting all the code for setting the LED lights which is still available in the link above. Problem B started occurring before I did this, so I don't think that has anything to do with it. Just didn't want to include the LEDs in my project.

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!! If there's any information I've missed out on, please let me know.

Edit: Okay, so I had the RX and TX wires of the module in the incorrect sockets. The RXD of the hc-05 module is now in pin 11 and the TXD in pin 10. Data is being transmitted, but it just endlessly keeps incrementing the shots even if the proximity sensor isn't detecting anything. :/ Any suggestions?

Edit2: Alright, issue resolved. I hadn't set the correct baud rate in the Bluetooth setup portion. Should've been 9600.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Serial1(10, 11); // RX, TX

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Filename    : Scoreboard.ino                                               //
// Description : Smart Basketball Scoreboard                                  //
// Version     : 1.1.0                                                        //
// Author      : Marcelo Avila de Oliveira <marceloavilaoliveira@gmail.com>   //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// DEFINITIONS                                                                //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// TURN ON DEBUG MODE
// #define DEBUG
// #define DEBUG_PROX
// #define DEBUG_VIBR

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// CONSTANTS                                                                  //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// PINS
const int prox_pin = 2;
const int vibr_pin = 3;

// TIME
const unsigned long wait_interval = 3000;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// VARIABLES                                                                  //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// TIME
unsigned long wait_time;

// STATUS
boolean prox = false;
boolean vibr = false;
boolean wait = false;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// FUNCTIONS (SETTINGS)                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void setup() {
    // INITIATE PINS
    pinMode(prox_pin, INPUT);
    pinMode(vibr_pin, INPUT);

    // INITIATE SERIAL COMMUNICATION
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // INITIATE BLUETOOTH COMMUNICATION
    setup_bluetooth();


    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.println("Board is alive");
        Serial.println();
    #endif
}

void setup_bluetooth() {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.println("Setting Bluetooth");
        Serial.println();
    #endif

    Serial1.begin(38400);                   // Set baud rate
    Serial1.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n");     // Set to work in slave mode
    Serial1.print("\r\n+STNA=Arduino\r\n"); // Set name
    Serial1.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n");     // Permit Paired device to connect me
    Serial1.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n");     // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
    delay(2000);                            // This delay is required.
    Serial1.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n");        // Make the slave inquirable 
    delay(2000);                            // This delay is required.
    while (Serial1.available()) {           // Clear data
        delay(50);
        Serial1.read();
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// FUNCTIONS (CHECK)                                                          //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void check_prox() {
    if (!prox) {
        if(digitalRead(prox_pin) == LOW) {
            #ifdef DEBUG_PROX
                Serial.println("Proximity detected");
                Serial.println();
            #endif

            prox = true;
            if (!vibr) {
                wait = true;
                wait_time = millis() + wait_interval;
            }
            set_shot(1);
        }
    }
}

void check_vibr() {
    if (!prox && !vibr) {
        if(digitalRead(vibr_pin) == HIGH) {
            #ifdef DEBUG_PROX
                Serial.println("Vibration detected");
                Serial.println();
            #endif

            vibr = true;
            wait = true;
            wait_time = millis() + wait_interval;
        }
    }
}

void check_wait() {
    if (wait && millis() > wait_time) {
        if (!prox) {
            set_shot(0);
        }
        reset();
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// FUNCTIONS (MIS)                                                            //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void set_shot(int mode) {
    // MODE:
    // 0 = WRONG SHOT (MISS)
    // 1 = RIGHT SHOT (SCORE)

    Serial1.print(mode);
    delay(1000);
}

void reset() {
    vibr = false;
    prox = false;
    wait = false;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// MAIN                                                                       //
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void loop() {
    check_prox();
    check_vibr();
    check_wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, issue resolved. I hadn't set the correct baud rate in the Bluetooth setup portion. Should've been 9600.